# SQL Server - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. ErrorCode HY000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute the query bellow on a SQL server database 
but it throws the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Code:

```
IF @status = 1
BEGIN
   ..... -- execute something 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select top #URL.nof# * 
    from lead_feed
    where
        lead_tstamp > '2017-09-01'
        and egoiID is not null
        and rtrim(ltrim(lead_name)) <> ''
        and rtrim(ltrim(lead_surname)) <> ''
        and rtrim(ltrim(lead_gender)) <> ''
        and rtrim(ltrim(lead_interest)) <> ''
        and lead_country in (select campaign_country 
                             from client_campaigns
                             where campaignID = '#URL.ccampaignID#')
        and leadID not in (select leadID 
                           from lead_integration
                           where campaignID = '#URL.ccampaignID#')
    order by 
        lead_tstamp desc
END
```

It points to the `leadID not in ( ....` part, if I delete this part it points the same error to `and lead_country in ( ...` part.

Can you please explain me whats happening?

Thanks.

Comment: 'LF.lead_country =' ......... should be replace with 'LF.lead_country in', or take max() or min() of that subquery

Comment: @Rams, I fixed it but still got the same error...

Comment: Too big query. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: after fixing that where you are getting error??

Comment: @Rams, the error its comming from the code on `else` statement and its on the line of `and leadID not in ( select leadID from lead_integration where campaignID = '#URL.ccampaignID#' )`.

Comment: is that subquery 'select leadID from lead_integration where campaignID = '#URL.ccampaignID#' ' works fine

Comment: @Rams yes, if i execute it seperated it works just fine...

Comment: What is `#URL.nof#`? Number, variable?

Comment: Agree with @Rokuto. Never seen syntax with the `#` before on the `Top` clause. Hardcode a number and see if that works.

Comment: I'm usign coldfusion #URL.*# its how you call URL parameters to construct your query.

Comment: Change it to number e.g. `100` and check if it executes without errors.

Comment: Please, add the query that runs into the database. You need to check how your code is replacing the ## fields and creating the final SQL.